# How to ensure my firewalls allows some IP addresses?

Tags: auth0

Auth0 is asking me to take action for my account in region Europe.

I understand that firewall should allow those IPs addresses that specified for Europe region, Shall add them manually at my auth0 dashboard ? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to manually add the IPs in the Auth0 Dashboard. The notice is to let you know the whitelisted IP address range been updated, so if you depend on that then you should make some adjustments accordingly.

For example, when Auth0 Rules & Custom DB (Connection) scripts run (login.js / getEmail.js etc) they do so from pre-defined list of IP addresses. We are then free to **whitelist** those **Auth0 IP addresses** as trusted source IPs in our APIs etc that these scripts call out to.

For example, (using JS / Node.js) you may have something simple like:

```
  var isAllowedIp = (req) => {
    var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress;
    var ips = config.ALLOWED_IP_LIST ? config.ALLOWED_IP_LIST.split(',') : [];
    return ips.indexOf(ip) !== -1;
  }
```

Then you test inside your API with:

```
if (!isAllowedIp(req)) {
      return res.boom.forbidden('Forbidden');
    }
```

Perhaps we could clean up the above by making it more declarative using middleware with Express.js etc - illustration only.  Realistically, this might be a firewall rule, rather than baked into the application logic as above.

Navigating from the Auth0 dashboard to `Connections -> Database -> Custom Database` (enabled) then we can find the IPs listed towards bottom of the page eg.

[image]

Comment: ah, I see, so as I am currently not validating IP addresses, there is no action that I shall do, right?

Comment: Correct, no action.